# How to disable createdAt field in a Sequelize model?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need an updatedAt field, but not a createdAt field.

So, I wrote this model:

```js
  const Vote = sequelize.define('Vote', {
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false },
    type: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true },
    userId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    postId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false }
  });
```

However, when I try to find a row, Sequelize includes createdAt for some reason. I've also tried just removing the `createdAt: false`, but it makes no difference.

Do I just have to manually filter out `createdAt` in all my queries?

Shouldn't this be controlled by my model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you can disable `createdAt` while keeping `updatedAt` by disabling timestamps, and then manually adding back `updatedAt` with a literal timestamp type to set `updatedAt` automatically as normal.

Like this:

```js
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    },
    type: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true },
    userId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    postId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false }
  },
  { timestamps: false }
  );
```